# Similar icons to SF Pro Symbols

Tags: fonts, icon, font-recommendation, resource-recommendations, apple

If I good understand developer can use SF Pro symbols in Apple products only, on iPhone, Mac, iPad. But if we develop something also for web, it can not be used, do you know any similar icon set can be used for web?

Those icons we need:

[image]

Comment: That's likely because the font is only installed on Apple devices. The font would work on other devices it if was installed. However, as far as I know, there are no restriction on using the symbols/glyphs of that font (or any font) as a graphic: such as a raster image, vector image, or in print, if you already own a licence to use it (which you do, since it was included with your mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font Awesome or Material by Google could be a good start, but there are many others.

- https://fontawesome.com/icons
- https://fonts.google.com/icons